# After going in sleep mode, Chrome tells me it's "Unable to access the network"

Tags: google-chrome, browser, windows

When I start my computer (Windows 8.1), I can open Google Chrome (34.0.1847.137) and browse the web. However, if I lock my computer or if Windows starts to hibernate, and I unlock or wake up Windows, I can't use Chrome anymore.

Closing Chrome and opening doesn't help. Shutting down all services related to Chrome doesn't work. I can browse sites using Firefox and MSIE, but Chrome keeps telling me "Unable to access the network."

I uninstalled Chrome, reinstalled Chrome, but I don't have any clue what can bring Chrome alive after locking/hibernating. The only thing that does work is a full reboot of Windows.

Comment: I have the same problem. This started when I started using Windows 8 (already about 2 years ago). Did you foudn a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately not...

Comment: What Virusscanner / Firewall do you use?

Comment: I had Clamwin as my virus scanner. Unfortunately the computer that demonstrated this behavior was stolen, so I can not check if the problem can be solved by removing the virus scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may sound silly, but when this happens to me with Chrome (and IE is working), I just do a simple on-off of the Wi-Fi in Windows. It might be worth a try.

Comment: I upgraded to Windows 10 and it doesn't happen anymore, so I can't test if it works. I've up-voted your answer, but since I can no longer test it, I'm not sure if I should accept it.